# Chrome Extension: executeScript on tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've recently started developing my first Google Chrome Extension, and am experiencing an issue that I'm not entirely sure how to fix.

In my script, I'm checking if a tab is open to a specific website, and, if so, I'm performing the following code:

```
chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {active: true});

// Execute code on the existing tab to open the Message.
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    "code": "messageOpen(15, false);"
});
```

The above code should update the tab setting it as active and should then attempt to execute a function called `messageOpen()`. The problem I'm experiencing is that the function `messageOpen()` exists as a function that was included in the `<HEAD>` of my website, but **not** my extension.

Hence, when attempting to execute the `messageOpen()` function, I'm receiving this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: messageOpen is not defined
```

I'm 100% positive that the `messageOpen()` function works if I browse the website regularly, but when using `executeScript`, it's as if the extension is incapable of running functions that have already been loaded in my active tab.

Does anybody have some suggestions or alternatives?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens because **content scripts cannot interact with the `window` object of the page they are injected to**. If you want to execute a script that uses your `messageOpen()` function then **you'll have to inject that code into the page context** using a `<script>`, like this:

```
var myScript = document.createElement('script');
myScript.textContent = 'messageOpen(15, false);';
document.head.appendChild(myScript);
```

So, if you want to inject this code using the `executeScript()` method and the `"code"` property you can do it like this:

```
chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {active: true});

// Execute code on the existing tab to open the Message.
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    "code": "var myScript = document.createElement('script');"
        + "myScript.textContent = 'messageOpen(15, false);';"
        + "document.head.appendChild(myScript);"
});
```

**NOTE**: since January 2021, use [Manifest V3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/) with [`chrome.scripting.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-executeScript) instead of `chrome.tabs.executeScript()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working sample to execute js on a tab for Manifest v3:

```js
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
  target: { tabId: tab.id },
  func: () => {
    // write your code here
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  },
});
```

You also need to add `scripting` permission to Manifest.json

```json
 permissions: [
    'scripting', // to execute js into a tab
  ],
```